# Horizontal dragging is blocking the default vertical scroll of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mobile

I have created a [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yNPzeg) of what I'm trying to achieve.

I'm creating a timeline overview with a couple of horizontal draggable items. Next to `jquery` and `jquery-ui`, I am also using `jquery-ui-touch-punch` for make all the gestures possible on mobile devices. On desktop everything works fine but not on mobile.

Unfortunately is the `$(".timeLineItemContainer").draggable({ ... });` extremely aggressive that it also swallows my vertical scrolling behavior which results in a page where I can't scroll down **on mobile** when I touch 1 of the items.

Somehow I need to enable or disable the drag capability of an item, depending on the direction of my scroll action. When I disable the `event.preventDefault();` in the `jquery-ui-touch-punch.js` it scrolls down, only then the `click` and `horizontal move` doesn't work properly (a horizontal swipe on mobile refers to a history.goback, which I want to prevent as I need it for my gesture).

To sum things up: All I want is to prevent the default behaviors, except for the vertical scroll.

Any thoughts of how to achieve this? Or are there any other ideas/approaches to achieve this?

[Here's a link for a mobile version](http://beta.tst.getroadmap.com/index3.html)

**HTML** (just a simple list of multiple items)

```
        <div class="timeLineItemContainer">
        <div class="subItemMiddleContainer">
            <div class="timeLineHeader">
                <div>
                    <span>A TITLE</span>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <div>Some other text text</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="subItemBottomContainer">
            <ul>
                <li class="static">
                    <div class="timeLineRight timeLineInfo">
                        <span class="info">Thu 12 March</span>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="static">
                    <div class="timeLineRight timeLineInfo">
                        <span class="label">some additional text</span>
                        <span class="info time strikethrough">bla</span>
                        <div class="info time attention">
                            <span>yup</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="toggable closed">
                    <div class="timeLineRight timeLineInfo">
                        <span class="label">Text</span>
                        <span class="info">content</span>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="toggable closed">
                    <div class="timeLineRight timeLineInfo">
                        <span class="label">title</span>
                        <span class="info">value</span>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="toggable closed">
                    <div class="timeLineRight timeLineInfo">
                        <span class="label">Another title</span>
                        <span class="info">another value</span>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="static">
                    <div class="timeLineRight timeLineInfo">
                        <span class="label">always visible</span>
                        <span class="info time strikethrough">just because</span>
                        <div class="info attention">
                            <span>attention!</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="timeLineItemContainer">
        <div class="subItemMiddleContainer">
            <div class="timeLineLeft">
                <div class="timeLinePipe"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="timeLineHeader">
                <div>
                    <span>Some other text</span>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <div>Ola!</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="subItemBottomContainer">
            <ul>

                <li class="static">
                    <div class="timeLineRight timeLineInfo">
                        <span class="info">A date</span>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="toggable closed">
                    <div class="timeLineRight timeLineInfo">
                        <span class="label">label</span>
                        <span class="info">value</span>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="toggable closed">
                    <div class="timeLineRight timeLineInfo">
                        <span class="label">anotehr label</span>
                        <span class="info time">different value</span>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="timeLineItemContainer">
        <div class="subItemMiddleContainer">
            <div class="timeLineHeader">
                <div>
                    <span>A TITLE</span>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <div>Some other text text</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="subItemBottomContainer">
            <ul>
                <li class="static">
                    <div class="timeLineRight timeLineInfo">
                        <span class="info">Thu 12 March</span>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="static">
                    <div class="timeLineRight timeLineInfo">
                        <span class="label">some additional text</span>
                        <span class="info time strikethrough">bla</span>
                        <div class="info time attention">
                            <span>yup</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="toggable closed">
                    <div class="timeLineRight timeLineInfo">
                        <span class="label">Text</span>
                        <span class="info">content</span>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="toggable closed">
                    <div class="timeLineRight timeLineInfo">
                        <span class="label">title</span>
                        <span class="info">value</span>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="toggable closed">
                    <div class="timeLineRight timeLineInfo">
                        <span class="label">Another title</span>
                        <span class="info">another value</span>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="static">
                    <div class="timeLineRight timeLineInfo">
                        <span class="label">always visible</span>
                        <span class="info time strikethrough">just because</span>
                        <div class="info attention">
                            <span>attention!</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="timeLineItemContainer">
        <div class="subItemMiddleContainer">
            <div class="timeLineLeft">
                <div class="timeLinePipe"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="timeLineHeader">
                <div>
                    <span>Some other text</span>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <div>Ola!</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="subItemBottomContainer">
            <ul>

                <li class="static">
                    <div class="timeLineRight timeLineInfo">
                        <span class="info">A date</span>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="toggable closed">
                    <div class="timeLineRight timeLineInfo">
                        <span class="label">label</span>
                        <span class="info">value</span>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="toggable closed">
                    <div class="timeLineRight timeLineInfo">
                        <span class="label">anotehr label</span>
                        <span class="info time">different value</span>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**Javascript**

```
var sw = screen.width;
var thresholdPercentageSwipeTimeLineItem = 15;
var thresholdPercentageSwipeDetailScreen = 10;    

$(".timeLineItemContainer").draggable({
    scroll: false,
    axis: "x",
    drag: function (event, ui) {
        if (ui.position.left < 0) {
            ui.position.left = 0;
        }
        else {
          if (calculateOffsetPercentage(ui.position.left) > thresholdPercentageSwipeTimeLineItem) {
              return false;
          };
        }
    },
    stop: function (event, ui) {
        $(this).animate({
           left: 0,
        }, {
           duration: 200,
           queue: false
        });
    }
}).click(function () {
    var nextObjs = $(this).toggleClass("visible").find(".toggable");

    $.each(nextObjs, function () {
        $(this).stop().animate({
            height: "toggle",
            queue: false
        }).toggleClass("closed");
    });

});

function calculateOffsetPercentage(screenValue) {
    return (100 / (sw / screenValue));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nailed it!

On first thoughts it looks like the `$(".timeLineItemContainer").draggable({ ... });` is consuming all of the events, but it is actually the `jquery-ui-touch-punch.js` who is preventing everything.

`jquery-ui-touch-punch.js` works in a way that all the touch events results are prevented to execute the default behavior. Therefore I tweaked the `jquery-ui-touch-punch.js` a bit to get the right behavior.

1. I removed the `event.preventDefault()` from the `simulateMouseEvent()` function.
2. I store the start of the touch in the `mouseProto._touchStart` event

   `tsx = event.originalEvent.touches[0].clientX;
    tsy = event.originalEvent.touches[0].clientY;`
3. I added a condition inside the `mouseProto._touchMove` event to check if I'm scrolling in a horizontal or vertical direction. In case of a horizontal direction I'm executing the `event.preventDefault()`. To get to that, you can use:

   `// Higher then 1 means a (more) horizontal direction
   // Lower then 1 means a (more) vertical direction
   // 1 is an exact 45 degrees swipe, which will be handled as a vertical swipe 
   if ((Math.abs(CurrentX - StartX)) / Math.abs(CurrentY - StartY) > 1) {
          event.preventDefault();
   }`

The endresult of the `mouseProto._touchStart` and the `mouseProto._touchMove` function look like this:

```
var tsx = 0, 
    tsy = 0, 
    currentx = 0, 
    currenty = 0;

mouseProto._touchStart = function (event) {
    var self = this;

    tsx = event.originalEvent.touches[0].clientX;
    tsy = event.originalEvent.touches[0].clientY;

    // Ignore the event if another widget is already being handled
    if (touchHandled || !self._mouseCapture(event.originalEvent.changedTouches[0])) {
        return;
    }

    // Set the flag to prevent other widgets from inheriting the touch event
    touchHandled = true;

    // Track movement to determine if interaction was a click
    self._touchMoved = false;

    //// Simulate the mouseover event
    simulateMouseEvent(event, 'mouseover');

    //// Simulate the mousemove event
    simulateMouseEvent(event, 'mousemove');

    // Simulate the mousedown event
    simulateMouseEvent(event, 'mousedown');

};

mouseProto._touchMove = function (event) {
    // Ignore event if not handled
    if (!touchHandled) {
        return;
    }

    // Higher then 1 means a (more) horizontal direction
    // Lower then 1 means a (more) vertical direction
    // 1 is an exact 45 degrees swipe, which will be handled as a vertical swipe
    if ((Math.abs(event.originalEvent.changedTouches[0].clientX - tsx)) / Math.abs(event.originalEvent.changedTouches[0].clientY - tsy) > 1) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }

    // Interaction was not a click
    this._touchMoved = true;

    // Simulate the mousemove event
    simulateMouseEvent(event, 'mousemove');
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried the OPs solution, but I think jQuery UI `draggable` may have changed since you last made this post. In my tests, even after completely removing `jquery-ui-touch-punch.js` I found that the drag event was still being consumed by jQuery UI `draggable`. I didn't want to dig into the jQuery UI code and fork the library, so I devised a fairly simple alternative.

In my scenario I had an inbox list whose items that you could drag to the left or right to expose action buttons. The entire inbox item must be draggable -- so the use of a drag handle was not an option.

jQuery's `draggable` prevents vertical scrolling on touch screens if the touch was initiated inside a `draggable` element. So if the screen was filled with draggable inbox items, then the user would become trapped -- unable to scroll up or down.

The solution that worked for me was to measure any change in the cursor's vertical position and use `window.scrollBy` to manually scroll the window by the same amount:

```
var firstY = null;      
var lastY = null;
var currentY = null;
var vertScroll = false;
var initAdjustment = 0;

// record the initial position of the cursor on start of the touch
jqDraggableItem.on("touchstart", function(event) {
    lastY = currentY = firstY = event.originalEvent.touches[0].pageY;
});

// fires whenever the cursor moves
jqDraggableItem.on("touchmove", function(event) {
    currentY = event.originalEvent.touches[0].pageY;
    var adjustment = lastY-currentY;

    // Mimic native vertical scrolling where scrolling only starts after the
    // cursor has moved up or down from its original position by ~30 pixels.
    if (vertScroll == false && Math.abs(currentY-firstY) > 30) {
        vertScroll = true;
        initAdjustment = currentY-firstY;
    }

    // only apply the adjustment if the user has met the threshold for vertical scrolling
    if (vertScroll == true) {
        window.scrollBy(0,adjustment + initAdjustment);
        lastY = currentY + adjustment;
    }

});

// when the user lifts their finger, they will again need to meet the 
// threshold before vertical scrolling starts.
jqDraggableItem.on("touchend", function(event) {
    vertScroll = false;
});
```

This will closely mimic native scrolling on a touch device.

Comment: Could you please create a jsfiddle for this, thanks!