# JQuery Draggable with Touch Punch stops vertical scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using JQuery Draggable function and Touch Punch to produce a list of horizontal sliders that can be scrolled by clicking and dragging. It works great in touch and click devices. The problem I am facing is that if I try to scroll up or down in touch devices, it doesn't work.

I have looked through SO and found that removing "event.preventDefault" from TouchPunch allows vertical scrolling, the problem with this fix is, that it only works on some devices, and not all.

I am wondering if anyone has any other solutions, or alternative way of producing the same horizontal sliders that work on both touch and click events.

Here is Example code (JQuery Draggable):

```js
$(function() {
  var slides = $('#list1 ul').children().length;
  var slideWidth = $('#list1').width();
  var min = 0;
  var max = -((slides - 1) * slideWidth);

  $("#list1 ul").width(slides * slideWidth).draggable({
    axis: 'x',
    drag: function(event, ui) {
      if (ui.position.left > min) ui.position.left = min;
      if (ui.position.left < max) ui.position.left = max;
    }
  });

    $("#list2 ul").width(slides * slideWidth).draggable({
    axis: 'x',
    drag: function(event, ui) {
      if (ui.position.left > min) ui.position.left = min;
      if (ui.position.left < max) ui.position.left = max;
    }
  });


});
```

```css
#list1 {
  position: relative;
  height: 16em;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: middle;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

#list1 .floating-box {
  margin: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 15em;
  height: 13.5em;
  margin: 0.1em;
  border: 0.2em solid black;
  background-color: white;
}

#list2 {
  position: relative;
  height: 16em;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: middle;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

#lis2 .floating-box {
  margin: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 15em;
  height: 13.5em;
  margin: 0.1em;
  border: 0.2em solid black;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="list1">
    <ul>
    <p>One</p>
    <div class="floating-box">Floating box</div>
    <div class="floating-box">Floating box</div>
    <div class="floating-box">Floating box</div>
    </ul>
 </div>


  <div id="list2">
    <ul>
     <p>Two</p>
     <div class="floating-box">Floating box</div>
     <div class="floating-box">Floating box</div>
     <div class="floating-box">Floating box</div>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

If I touch list1 or list2 div and try to scroll up or down, it doesn't recognize the movement. Any help or direction would be appreciated.

Comment: try this https://jqueryui.com/draggable/

Comment: @kyunghwanjung That's what I am currently using, the "draggable" function, the issue is, I can't scroll up and down.

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT**
Based on the idea to determine theswipe direction based on the `pageY` propertie of `touchemove`.

I think it's a good idea to avoid the annoying double tap *(see first answer below)* on the long run.
There is still a compromise on it, but it is much more reasonable.

I tried many things... The best result I got is when I gave up on simulating a scroll on `touchmove`.

**So here is the way to I now use each of the three touch events:**

- ***touchstart*** gets the initial variables like: window scrollTop and pageY.
- ***touchmove*** determines the swipe direction and gets the last pageY.
- ***touchend*** does the math as to were the page should scrollTo.
  For the cuteness, I've put that result value in an `.animate()`.
  I was pleasantly surprised to see that it compensates quite really smoothly the fact that the page scrolls only on `touchend`.
  I think that very few users will notice it ;).

Since "Touch-Punch" is working by default for horizontal swipes, the "compromise" only affects the vertical scroll.

Here is the code:
And a [**live link**](https://www.bessetteweb.com/SO/40799506/touch-punch-fixed-v2.html) to try it on a touche-enabled device.

```
$(function() {
    var slides = $('#list1 ul').children().length;
    var slideWidth = $('#list1').width();
    var min = 0;
    var max = -((slides - 1) * slideWidth);

    $(".draggable").width(slides * slideWidth).draggable({
        axis: 'x',
        drag: function(event, ui) {
            if (ui.position.left > min) ui.position.left = min;
            if (ui.position.left < max) ui.position.left = max;
        }
    });

    var startTouchX=0;
    var startTouchY=0;

    var actualPosX;
    var actualPosY;

    var eventCounter=0;
    var directionDetermined=false;
    var direction;

    var thisTouchX;
    var thisTouchY;

    var lastTouchY;

    $(document).on("touchstart", function(e) {
        // Actual document position
        actualPosX = $(document).scrollLeft();
        actualPosY = $(document).scrollTop();

        // StartTouches
        startTouchX = parseInt(e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX);
        startTouchY = parseInt(e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageY);
    });

    $(document).on("touchmove", function(e) {

        // Arbitrary considering ONLY the fourth event... 
        // Touchmove fires way too many times!
        // We only need to determine the main direction ONCE.
        // This prevents an "s" swipe from messing this code.
        eventCounter++;
        if(eventCounter==4 && !directionDetermined){

            thisTouchX = parseInt(e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX);
            thisTouchY = parseInt(e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageY);

            if ( (Math.abs(thisTouchX - startTouchX)) / Math.abs(thisTouchY - startTouchY) > 1){     //check swipe direction

                // HORIZONTAL
                $("#debug").html("HORIZONTAL");
                directionDetermined=true;

                // NO NEED here. This is re-enabled on touchend, if it has been disabled.
                //$(".draggable").draggable('enable');
            }
            else{

                // VERTICAL
                $("#debug").html("VERTICAL");
                directionDetermined=true;
                direction="vertical";

                $(".draggable").draggable('disable'); // Disable draggable.
            }
        }

        // Getting all the Y touches...
        // The "last" value will be used on touchend.
        lastTouchY = parseInt(e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageY);
        //$("#debug").html(lastTouchY);
    });

    $(document).on("touchend", function(e) {
            if(direction=="vertical"){
                //$("#debug").html(lastTouchY);

                var thisMoveY = -parseInt(lastTouchY - startTouchY);
                //$("#debug").html(thisMoveY);

                var newPosY = (actualPosY + thisMoveY);
                //$("#debug").html(actualPosX+ " " +newPosY);

                //window.scrollTo(actualPosX, newPosY);
                $("html,body").animate({ scrollTop: newPosY },400);
            }

            // Reset everything for a future swipe.
            startTouchX=0;
            startTouchY=0;
            eventCounter=0;
            directionDetermined=false;
            direction="";
            $("#debug").html("");

            // Re-enable draggable.
            $(".draggable").draggable('enable');
    });
});
```

---

**First answer, using a "double-tap" to switch direction.**

First, the Touch Punch website states that it's basically a jQuery-UI *hack* to handle *some* cases actually unhandled by jQuery-UI...
And that it is possible to find cases where Touch Punch fails.

Your issue was reported to the Touch Punch developpers [here](https://github.com/furf/jquery-ui-touch-punch/issues/270).
As an answer to that *(in my words here)*, they said that it isn't really bug or an issue...
But a usage "conflict" on two different "wished" actions that are using the same touch events.
Sometimes to scroll the page, and sometimes to drag an element.

As a solution hint, they posted [this Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/77e7ytwk/).
It suggests to find a way to disable draggable when needed.

But in this solution, the scrollable section is **within** the draggable element.
Which is not your case.
And you use almost all the mobile screen space for your draggable elements, so there is not enougth space left to trigger a `draggable("disable")` around them.

So... I had this idea, which I hope will help.

What if you'd find an elegant way to inform your users that a "double-tap" changes the movement orientation.
Here, I suggest a quite simple "double arrow" showing the movement direction.
Maybe you'll find something better.

This sure is a little compromise user experience, to ask them to double tap...
But if your layout really needs it, maybe it's ok.

So here, I reproduced your [initial issue](https://www.bessetteweb.com/SO/40799506/touch-punch.html).
And here is [the fix that I suggest](https://www.bessetteweb.com/SO/40799506/touch-punch-fixed.html).

I only tryed it on a Samsung Galaxy S3, but should work on every touch device.

```
$(function() {
    var slides = $('#list1 ul').children().length;
    var slideWidth = $('#list1').width();
    var min = 0;
    var max = -((slides - 1) * slideWidth);

    $(".draggable").width(slides * slideWidth).draggable({
        axis: 'x',
        drag: function(event, ui) {
            if (ui.position.left > min) ui.position.left = min;
            if (ui.position.left < max) ui.position.left = max;
        }
    });

    // Flag
    var draggableEnabled=true;

    // Find the doubletap position (to show a nice double arrow)
    var tapPosition=[];
    $(document).on("touchstart",function(e){
        tapPosition[0] = parseInt(e.touches[0].pageX) - $(document).scrollLeft() - ($("#arrows img").width()/2);
        tapPosition[1] = parseInt(e.touches[0].pageY) - $(document).scrollTop() - ($("#arrows img").width()/2);
    });

    Hammer(document).on("doubletap", function() {
        //alert("Double tap");
        draggableEnabled = !draggableEnabled;   // Toggle

        if(!draggableEnabled){
            $(".draggable").draggable('disable');   // Disables draggable (and touch Punch)
            $("#arrows img").css({
                    "transform":"rotate(90deg)",    // Nice vertical double arrow
                    "top":tapPosition[1],
                    left:tapPosition[0]
                }).fadeIn(600, function(){
                $(this).fadeOut(600);
            });

        }else{
            $(".draggable").draggable('enable');    // Enables draggable (and touch Punch)
            $("#arrows img").css({
                    "transform":"rotate(0deg)",     // Nice horizontal double arrow
                    "top":tapPosition[1],
                    left:tapPosition[0]
                }).fadeIn(600, function(){
                $(this).fadeOut(600);
            });
        }
    }); 
});
```

Notice that it uses the [Hammer.js](http://hammerjs.github.io/) ([CDN](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/hammer.js)) to detect the double tap.

And some extra CSS for the [double arrow](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/f/ff/Double-arrow.svg).

```
#arrows img{
    width: 60vw;
    height: 60vw;
    position: fixed;
    top:calc( 50vh - 60vw );
    left:calc( 50vh - 60vw );
    z-index:1000;
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: This is a great idea in my opinion, I tested it in other devices and it works great. It would effect user experience slightly, I will definitely consider this if no other answer is available. Thanks Louys!

Comment: Could you please check my answer and see if you can complete it? Thanks!

Comment: I've done something based on your super great idea for direction determination. I will edit soon.

Comment: Nicely done, it is the closest to the solution in SO :)

Answer (score 1):

This is the closest I have come to it, I wonder if someone could refine this code:

```
$(watchlist).on("touchstart", function(e) {
        touchY = e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageY;
        touchX = e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX;

    });

    $(watchlist).on("touchmove", function(e) {

        var fTouchY = e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageY;
        var fTouchX = e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX;

        if ((Math.abs(fTouchX - touchX)) / Math.abs(fTouchY - touchY) > 1){ //check swipe direction

            $("#watchlist ul").draggable( 'enable'); //if swipe is horizontal
        }
        else{
            $("#watchlist ul").draggable( 'disable'); //if swipe is horizontal
        }


    });
```

The problem with this code is, that it deactivates the draggable function only after the touch move has been finished rather than during. If anyone could modify this code so that the draggable function is deactivated during as soon as the condition is met, during `touchmove`, rather than after, I would give them the bounty.

Comment: I found a working solution in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31024233/horizontal-dragging-is-blocking-the-default-vertical-scroll-of-the-page#answer-40247686